# Conitional output style of kable/kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

Is there any ability to write a function to export `kable` or `kableExtra` tables as different formats based on the output that `knitr` creates.

Specifically, I would want `format = "simple"` for `.docx` and `format = "html"` for `.html`.

I cannot find any examples of this so not sure if it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be helpful (`eval=knitr::is_html_output()` for the `html` chunk):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Conditional

```{r html, eval=knitr::is_html_output()}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, "html", booktabs = T)
```

```{r docx}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, "simple", booktabs = T)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about those functions. That helped be figure it out... See the answer below.

Comment: Nice, @AtanasJanackovski! Glad that I could help you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so thanks to [@bttomio's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249862/bttomio) answer, I figured out a solution that will work...

```r
## set options for knitr
options(
  knitr.table.format = ifelse(knitr::pandoc_to("docx"), "simple", "html")
)

## create var to call
kbl_frmt <- getOption("knitr.table.format")
```

Then when generating a table, something like:

```r
kbl(
  df,
  format = kbl_frmt,
  etc...
)
```

Which from my tests formats the tables based on the format outputted by `knitr`. There may be a more elegant solution, but at least was I only have to write code for one table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you in case you want to export your table in different format
use datatable it is more flexible than kable and short hint will be as below:

```
datatable(your dataframe, extenions=c('Buttons'),
#list column names to be displayed in the table
colnames=c("col1","col2",etc..),
options = list(
pageLength = 400,
dom = 'Bfrtip',
buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 2:7))
                )
)
```

After above code your table will be downloadable in mention formats